# Recursive Bayesian estimation for the coefficients of a convex combination

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior, filter

I'm given a sequential measurements of vectors $\vec{v}_t\in R^{K+1}$ such that $v_{t,0}$ is a convex combination of $\{v_{t,k}\}_{k\ge 1}$ (i.e. $v_{t.0}=\sum_{k\ge 1}{w_{t,k}v_{t,k}}$ for some weights $\vec{w}_t\in [0,1]^K$ satisfying $\sum{w_t}=1$).

I would like to track the sequences $\{\vec{w}_t\}_{t\ge 0}$. It is non-constant, but is assumed to evolve slowly (though not necessarily continuously) - so I can use $\vec{w}_t$ as a prior for $\vec{w}_{t+1}$.

I'm not very satisfied with my approach (described below), but while it seems highly likely this is a common setting - I couldn't find a "text-book solution". Is there one?

---

My approach: since I model a stochastic-vector, it seems reasonable to encode the knowledge $\vec{x}_t$ I gradually gain as a Dirichlet distribution which is the conjugate prior of the discrete distribution (so $\vec{w}_t\sim\mathrm{Dirichlet(x_t)}$).

But the stochastic-vector $\vec{w}_t$ does not actually represent a distribution, and I don't observe "counting data" $\vec{c}_t$ that can be used for a Bayesian update $x_{t+1}\leftarrow x_t + c_t$.

So instead, I'm looking for a correction $y_t$ that satisfies the constrain $\langle \frac{\vec{x}_t+y_t}{||\vec{x}_t+y_t||_{\ell_1}}, \vec{v}_{t,k\ge 1} \rangle = v_{t,0}$. The  solutions for this equation are given by -
$$y_t = \frac{v_{t,0}\sum_i{x^i_t}-\langle \vec{x}_t, \vec{v}_{t,k\ge 1} \rangle}{||\vec{v}_{t,k\ge 1}-v_{t,0}||^2}(\vec{v}_{t,k\ge 1}-v_{t,0})+\vec{u}$$

where $\vec{u}$ is any vector from the orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{span}\{\vec{v}_{t,k\ge 1}-v_{t,0}\}$. Those degrees of freedoms can used to find an admissible solution (by which I mean $c_t$ for which $x_{t,k}+y_{t,k}\ge 0$, which is a requirement from the parameters of the Dirichlet distribution).

Then I take $c_t:=x_t+y_t$  as the observation in time $t$, and I can apply $x_{t+1}\leftarrow 2x_t + y_t$.

If there are many admissible solutions $y_t$, I take the smallest one (according to either the $\ell_1$ or $\ell_2$ norm).

But if my observations are noisy (they actually are, but for clarity I omitted this issue for this questions), the equation above may have no admissible solutions. Currently I approximate a solution from the space of admissible solutions, and while it seems to works reasonably well on my data-set and my simulations - it feels quite hackish.